# Earliest legend of someone being turned into an animal/monster?

Tags: history, monsters

What is the earliest legend we know of, that involves someone (named or otherwise) being turned into an animal, or some terrible monster? This includes turning someone's unborn child into a monster, like the legend of the minotaur.

Comment: Lyacon from Greek mythology ?

Comment: Demeter transformed Ascalabus into a lizard for mocking her sorrow and thirst during her search for her daughter Persephone. She also turned King Lyncus into a lynx for trying to murder her prophet Triptolemus.

Comment: Some info can be gathered from Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapeshifting unfortunately I don't have time to make a satisfying answer anytime soon.